# how to make Edittext get bigger by animation after clicking on it

Tags: java, android

I'd like to get my Edit text bigger after starting writing on it.
as I show in image bellow.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55fbO.jpg)
so how should I do that?! Anyone has any idea!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need check focus on editText and set AnimatioValue

```
 edt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean hasfocus) {
                if (hasfocus) {
                    Log.e("TAG", "edt focused");
                    //ValueAnimator total
                    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 1.5f);
                    valueAnimator.setDuration(325);
                    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                            edt.setScaleX(value);
                            edt.setScaleY(value);
                            edt.requestLayout();
                        }
                    });
                    valueAnimator.start();
                } else {
                    Log.e("TAG", "edt not focused");
                    //animation inverse
                }
            }
 });
```

Comment: merci hamshahriii:)))

Comment: Parchame IRAN balast  